# Is the use of "boot" in "it'll boot you none to try" weird or strange?

Tags: word-usage, colloquialisms, phrasing

I seem to have a phrase in my head for a long time that i can't remember where I picked it up.

> It will boot you none to attempt this/try.

The implication being that there will be no advantage or benefit in trying or doing something.

Anybody else use it this way? I can't find a reference cause Google results are clogged with modern technical computer related results.
Is this a weird personal Mandela effect thing I came up with?

Comment: Google Books turns up a few obscure uses of "will boot you little" or "will boot you nothing" from the late 1800s / early 1900s, but no sources that you'd be likely to read. No results for "boot you none".

Comment: "It boots nothing to avoid his snares, for they are ever beset with other snares, and life and death are too intimately intergrown to be severed from each other."
—Mhoram's cryptic advice, given to Thomas Covenant in Andelain in The Wounded Land.

Comment: Zenitsu, "boot you nothing" is the usual phrase.  I have never heard "boot you none" and it's likely you remember it wrong.  "boot you nothing" is a common phrase.

Comment: ("boot" simply means profit)

Comment: @B.Goddard - what do you mean by cryptic?  What's cryptic about that sentence? (BTW, I happened to meet that Donaldson guy when he gave a talk at college. Everyone was asking complicated psychological questions and I asked if he used an electric or manual typewriter!)

Comment: @Fattie - and the answer was?

Comment: Never heard it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - he loved his electric typewriter!

Comment: @Fattie  The whole of my comment is cut-n-paste from a Donaldson website.  "Cryptic" isn't my word.

Answer (score 14):

This wasn't in the first online dictionary I looked in, so here's an answer.

> **boot** ... [2] [verb] (1) *booted; booting; boots*
>
> [archaic]: avail, profit

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boot)]

The sense is very rare nowadays, except in stylised historical fiction, poetry etc where 'What boots it?' ('What does that matter?' / 'What's the point?') may be encountered.

It is  used by Milton in *Lycidas* [[BBC Poetry](https://www.bbc.co.uk/poetryseason/poems/lycidas.shtml)] (beware the misplaced PP):

> ... Alas! what boots it with uncessant care
>
> To tend the homely slighted shepherd's trade,

........................

'will avail you none' (for which there are a handful of hits in a Google search) shows the 'none' = 'nothing' archaism
:

> **none** [1 of 4] [pronoun]
>
> singular or plural in construction  ...4: no part : NOTHING

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/none)]

[Actually, 'avail you not' is almost as common as 'avail you nothing', so one could argue for the adverb intercategorial polyseme of 'none' (= 'not at all') here.]

Comment: Maybe "And it's healthy, to boot" relates in meaning: *for further advantage*.

Comment: It is also used as a noun for 'payment, tangible benefit' in US (Federal) tax practice; in particular if a public (stock) corporation is acquired solely for (acquirer) stock it is usually not taxable to stockholders (at the time; it retains the prior basis for possible future tax), whereas if acquired for stock plus cash or other property, a stockholder must recognize (and pay tax on) gain but only up to the value of the cash/property, and this is informally(?) called 'gain within boot'. The first time I encountered this I thought they meant the boot you wear on your foot :-)

Comment: @YosefBaskin Indeed, the use of "to boot" to mean "in addition" derives from this usage, although it seems to have lost its positive connotation and may also indicate additional negative aspects.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie the phrase "and it's _ _, to boot" is entirely, totally, 100% positive.  It's identical to saying "and on top of that, it's _ _ _".

Comment: Edwin, you point out that the usage "what boots it" ("what does it matter") is now only poetic.  This may confuse the OP.  The OP is asking about the commonplace phrase "boots you nothing", and indeed, what the OP is asking is "can it be 'none' instead of 'nothing'?"  (Answer: No)

Comment: I see 1 hit on Google for "boots you nothing" but over 1 million (raw) for "what boots it", so 'commonplace' seems unhelpful.  'It will avail you none' (for which there _are_ hits) shows the 'none' = 'not at all' archaism.

Comment: Edwin, could the "what boots it" hits all be various poetry/similar?

Comment: @Fattie: It's an intensifier, and whether it is positive or negative depends on what it is used to intensify.  It certainly is not always a positive thing.

Comment: @Fattie "I lost my wallet, and my keys to boot." "The food was tasteless, and cold to boot."- there certainly is no requirement that the additional thing is a good one. The archaic usage was strictly positive, indicating some advantage or something included in a bargain, but in modern usage, characteristics "to boot" may or may not be desirable - they just strengthen whatever character was already present, positive or negative.

Comment: [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/commonplace) has '**commonplace**: happening or seen frequently and so not considered special or unusual'. Which doesn't apply to the expressions containing this sense of 'boot' (= 'avail').

Comment: ahh!  I see what you mean guys, "lost the keys to boot".  that's a **completely different word**.  It just means "moreover".  Op is asking about "boots" as in "profits".

Comment: @BenVoigt "to boot" has no connection in any way to intensifying.  it just means "and" or "moreover". That's all it means. Today is Tuesday, and the 15th to boot.

Comment: @Fattie *ahh! I see what you mean guys, "lost the keys to boot". that's a completely different word.* It isn't: it is preposition + noun and comes from the same root as the verb. -- OED 1.
  a. Good: in phrase to boot: ‘to the good’, to advantage, into the bargain, in addition; besides, moreover. -- Etymology: Common Germanic: Old English bót (feminine), Old Saxon bôta, Old High German buoȥa (Middle High German buoȥe , modern German busze ), Old Norse bót, Gothic bôta ‘**boot, advantage, good**’, probably a derivative of root bat- (Aryan *bhad- ) ‘good, useful’: see better adj., n.1, and adv.

Comment: I'd just like to again point out that this answer is an interesting essay, which has no connection, in any way, at all, to the question :) :)  The question is, **"Is the word None correct here?** That's all the OP is asking. That's it.  (Answer, it's "nothing" not "none".)

Comment: @Greybeard I appreciate that info but: (1) I don't know or care what the OED says; partially because (2) It's unclear what sense is referring to what. However, (3) in the phrase "boot[s] you nothing" the "boot" undeniably means "profit" and has no connection at all to "and / moreover". Whereas (4) in the phrase "it's Wednesday to boot" the "boot" undeniably means "also" or "moreover" and has no connection at all to "profit, advantage". I appreciate the phrase to boot is sometimes used in negative /humorously negative situations ("he's sick, and broke to boot") but that's a weak connection.

Comment: @Fattie that level of criticism of OED is not warranted. *Whereas (4) in the phrase "it's Wednesday to boot" the "boot" undeniably means "also" or "moreover" and has no connection at all to "profit, advantage".* I think that is one possible interpretation - but there is a clear connection - *undeniably* is far to strong. The root alone provides a connection...

Comment: @Greybeard I fear these QA can go **drastically** off kilter you know?  The question at hand is, in the idiom stated, "is it 'none'?" (answer, "no, it's 'nothing'").  We then started discussing the totally, completely unrelated idiom "to boot" (which has nothing, at all, to do with the question - in any way).  You and I are now discussing the etymology of various things!!!!  There is then an ongoing huge sub-discussion about whether the phrase the OP hearde someone say, "boots you nothing," is archaic {the OP heard it in real life, so perhaps he is archaic-aged! :) } Hence, cheers 4 now!

Answer (score 0):

##### "Boot" means profits. (As in pirate "booty", say.) Hence the common phrase "boots you nothing."

##### OP misheard "none" for "nothing".

> "... boot you nothing"

or

> "... boots you nothing"

is a commonplace phrase.

"... none" is a mishearing, it would be meaningless. ("None profit" is meaningless.)

An example usage, yesterday at work someone was talking about reprogramming a device (which has almost no sales, nobody uses it) and someone said "that will boot you nothing".

Another example, I notice in the US sports radio talkers often use this phrase. ("Team X to acquire player Y - hopeless, that will boot them nothing.")

---

##### Archaic?

Unrelated to your question:

Be aware that many contributors here assert "boots you nothing" is an archaic idiom.

---

##### Boot (unrelated) means "moreover". Hence the unrelated phrase ".. to boot".

"The food was expensive, and bad to boot." ... moreover.